# Тире или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Как вы думаете, что тут нужно подставить: "Я опоздал на работу (?) будильник не прозвонил"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение. Вторая часть обозначает причину того, о чем говорится в первой части, поэтому между частями этого предложения должно быть двоеточие.

Answer (score 1):

Между  частями этого сложного  бессоюзного предложения должно стоять двоеточие, так так вторая часть объясняет причину происходящего в первой